# Pi calculator with user input

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to make a pi calculator, where it prints how ever many digits of pi the user wants. I am trying to to have the users input become an integer, nut I'm not sure how to do that or if it will work. I am not sure if that will work. But please help, and thank you in advance.

```
picalc = input("How many digits: ")
    def make_pi():
        q, r, t, k, m, x = 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3
        for j in range(picalc):
            if 4 * q + r - t < m * t:
                yield m
                q, r, t, k, m, x = 10*q, 10*(r-m*t), t, k, (10*(3*q+r))//t - 10*m, x
            else:
                q, r, t, k, m, x = q*k, (2*q+r)*x, t*x, k+1, (q*(7*k+2)+r*x)//(t*x),x+2


    digits = make_pi()
    pi_list = []
    my_array = []

    for i in make_pi():
        my_array.append(str(i))

    my_array = my_array[:1] + ['.'] + my_array[1:]
    big_string = "".join(my_array)
    print (big_string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `int(picalc)` if you're okay with an exception being thrown if it's not parseable as an integer.

Otherwise you could make a try-catch construct to ask the user again for an input if it's not legal.

Comment: What I would recommend is that you have a while true: loop and when the person enters an integer to break the loop. Otherwise it keeps prompting them to enter an integer

Comment: CyanogenCX this piece of code was part of a larger project, when this piece of code finished it looped back to the begining of the program which was a prompt, but thank you.